# Why use address of variable to change the value of a variable?

Tags: c, pointers

In [page 15](https://mcs.utm.utoronto.ca/~209/lectures/w02/w02_furkan.pdf) of my lecture slide, there is an example.

```
int x = 10;
increment_int(x); // can’t change the value of x
increment2_int(&x); // can change the value of x
```

I don't understand why the first function `increment_int(x)` can't change the value of x. Though I don't know what those functions exactly do, I guess they are incrementing some amount to the argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- increment_int is pass by value. If the function increment_int changes
  the value of its parameter, it is only reflected in its local copy.
  The caller doesn't see the change.
- increment2_int is pass by reference. You pass the address of x rather
  the value of x to this function. This function changes the value of
  at the specified address which is reflected on the caller side too.

Comment: perhaps a nitpick, but _everything_ in C is pass-by-value. A pointer to `x` is passed to `increment2_int`. Since it's pass-by-value, a copy of that pointer is made inside `increment2_int`, this pointer and `&x` point to the same thing,, so when `x` is dereferenced in `increment2_int`, it points to `x` in the caller.